# How to properly organize routes in ExpressJS?

Tags: node.js, express, routes, mongoose

I'm developing my first test application on `NodeJS` and encountered the following problem: i can't figure out how to properly organize routes in `ExpressJS` framework. For example i want to do registration, so i create route like:

```
app.get('/registration', function (request, response) {
    if (request.body.user.email && request.body.user.password) {
        var user = new User();
        var result = user.createNew(request.body.user.email, request.body.user.email);

        // do stuff...
    }

    response.render('registration.html', config);
});
```

User function looks like this (not the final):

```
function User() {
    var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({ 
        'email': { 
            'type': String, 
            'required': true, 
            'lowercase': true, 
            'index': { 'unique': true }
        },
        'password': {
            'type': String, 
            'required': true
        }
    });

    var userModel = mongoose.model('users', userSchema);

    this.createNew = function(email, password) {
        var new_user = new users({'email': email, 'password': password});

        new_user.save(function(err){
            console.log('Save function');

            if (err)
                return false;

            return true;
        });
    }
}
```

I try to do a bit of structured applications like MVC. The problem is that the `save` method is asynch and each time i registrate new user get `registration.html` without waiting for the result.

Basically i need to run route callback in `save` callback, but how to do this in the right way i can't figure out by myself...

Answer (score 1):

```
this.createNew = function(email, password, callback) {
    var new_user = new users({'email': email, 'password': password});

    new_user.save(function(err){
        console.log('Save function');

        if (err)
            // return false;
            callback (false);
        else
            //return true;
            callback (true);
    });
}
```

I find that whenever I'm using some module (db for example) and it's using a callback, I will often have to also use a callback for any function I wrap around it (unless I don't care about the results).

Here:

```
app.get('/registration', function (request, response) {
    if (request.body.user.email && request.body.user.password) {
        var user = new User();
        // var result = user.createNew(request.body.user.email, request.body.user.email);

        user.createNew(request.body.user.email, request.body.user.email, function (results) {
             // do something with results (will be true or false)
             // not sure why you have this with the actual registration stuff,
             // but it's your site. :)
             response.render('registration.html', config);
        });
    }
});
```

Also, you might want to put your object methods in the prototype, instead of:

```
this.createNew = function (....) {}
```

Try:

```
User.prototype.createNew = function ( ... ) { }
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures#Performance_considerations  for info on why.

Answer (score 0):

For a starting point on organising your Node.js app, try reading through the source code on this demo express.js app. [Click here for the link](https://github.com/madhums/node-express-mongoose-demo)

It's a fairly popular repo, which I often find myself referencing when building Node.js apps from scratch.

It may be a good reference for your project given it's done in an the MVC style and it uses mongoose. The routes are organised into a single file which can be found in `config/routes.js`. You should also take a look at the models in `app/models/` for an alternative way to organise your user model